# How to style modals in ionic 5 with shadow dom

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have recently upgraded from Ionic 4 to 5 and none of my modal styling is working.  I've read the docs and what I'm doing seems like it should work.  In `global.scss` I have the following:

```
.modal-fullscreen .modal-wrapper {
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and when I create the modal, I use `modal-fullscreen` as the `cssClass` parameter.

```
  inviteClient( client : IndexClient ) : void {
    this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: InviteClientComponent,
      componentProps: {
        'consult_client': client,
        'location_id': this.location
      },
      backdropDismiss: false,
      cssClass: "modal-fullscreen"
    }).then( modal => modal.present());
  }
```

The docs clearly state that this should work here:

> We recommend passing a custom class to cssClass in the create method
> and using that to add custom styles to the host and inner elements.
> This property can also accept multiple classes separated by spaces.
> View the Usage section for an example of how to pass a class using
> cssClass.
>
> ```
> /* DOES NOT WORK - not specific enough */ .modal-wrapper {  
> background: #222; }
>
> /* Works - pass "my-custom-class" in cssClass to increase specificity
> */ .my-custom-class .modal-wrapper {   background: #222; }
> ```

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Exactly the same issue I´m having, i guess you never found a solution

Comment: I can't recall exactly but had to use something like this:

```.modal-fullscreen::part(content), ion-modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-wrapper {
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}```

Answer (score 0):

it's been some time, but it may help someone.

You can use [CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts), which ionic uses in it's components to customise it as you want.

See that modal-wrapper *classed* div inside ion-modal shadow-root has a part named "content", this is the one you should use in this case.
[ion-modal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPppE.png)

Your CSS should look like this:

```
ion-modal.modal-fullscreen::part(content) {
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also you can check the [ion-modal documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) for more ways of using the Ionic Modals. Using sheet modals, or more specific the **breakpoints** ModalOptions property could be a better way of achieving what you want.